# Android studio multiple projects in same window

Tags: android, android-studio

I usually work with multiple projects. Lately android studio added new feature of having 2+ projects shown in the same window. It looks very similar to the for example google chrome when you have open 3 tabs.
You can nicely and very fast switch between projects which is super useful.

Anyways sometimes when I open new projects, they are not "auto added" to this tab mode and I finish with having 2-3 projects and every project is in its own window.

I tried playing with View and Window part in android studio toolbar but did not manage to find solution yet. I believe it's something with Window.

Can someone please explain it here not only for me, but also for all android devs that have same question

Comment: For me this only works when AS is in fullscreen mode.

Comment: @Stephan for me sometimes it does and sometimes it does not. For example now I put both of my projects in full screen mode, but still they are in 2 windows so I need to swipe to see them (no tabs available)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macOS, you can use the "Merge project windows" setting.

- from the menu: `Window > Merge All Project Windows"`

You can find more information here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/open-close-and-move-projects.html#merge-project-windows